# How to change label color of a usercontrol from another usercontrol ? C# .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

i have this project with 3 usercontrols and 1 form, the usercontrols appear on the form when a button is pressed. Now i need to change a label color on let's say "UserControl3" by clicking a button located in "UserControl1", i tried the following code but it didnt work

```
var name = new UserControl3();
name.label.ForeColor = Color.Green;
```

i also tried another way but it threw an exception, image below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PhcU.jpg

i then found another way that almost works as intended, by removing and adding the usercontrol. The problem is that then it goes on the main form that is supposed to be empty

```
var name = new UserControl3();
this.Controls.Remove(name);
this.Controls.Add(name);
name.label1.ForeColor = Color.Green;
```

the code above almost works as i want but i dont think its a good solution and im pretty sure there are other easier ways to make this work... Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Of course you cannot do something like this: `var name = new UserControl3();`. You create a new Instance of an UC that's not related to any existing instance of `UserControl3`. -- What is the *relation* between these UserControl? How can one know of the existence of another? It doesn't (and it shouldn't). You need another object that takes care of creating a relation between these *parts* . Call it a Controller. You can also make your UCs raise events and expose public methods and/or properties that allow to interact with their internal components.

Comment: E.g., when a  Button in your UC1 is clicked, UC1 raises an Event (public). You can make your Form subscribe to this event (or use a *Controller* class). When the event is raised, the Form (or Controller), call a public method of UC3 that allows to set the color of one of its internal components. In this case, even if the Control that *changes color* is replaced, the external code remains the same -- Never (ever) expose a child Control of an UC changing its access modifier to `public`.

Comment: i understood what is wrong, reading your answer everything is more clear but now i dont know how i could create this "controller" to put the usercontrols in relation. I understood that i have to create a class called controller

Comment: Before you look for it ([MVC Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), [MVP Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter), [MVVM Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel)), use your Form class to subscribe to a public event of UC1 and use this event to call a public method of UC3. You have to make both, so learn how to raise a custom event and how to expose a public method. -- After that, take a look at those patterns. You'll find it useful (yes, all have their learning curve).

Comment: Also note that you necessarily need to know the base OOP principles, otherwise you'll have a very hard time making a fully functional application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to re-create an instance of usercontrol but use the first instance created and just change the color of the control.

just this code:

```
name.label.ForeColor = Color.Green;
```

Define this code globally

```
var name = new UserControl3();
```